# CGAC2022 Day 21: Present stack headache

Tags: code-golf, 3d, packing

Part of [**Code Golf Advent Calendar 2022**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25251/announcing-code-golf-advent-calendar-2022-event-challenge-sandbox) event. See the linked meta post for details.

---

*challenge idea by [emanresu A](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62441610#62441610)*

Santa has a bunch of presents wrapped in cuboid boxes of various sizes. As his sled flies above a chimney, a stack of presents will be automatically dropped through it. Santa wants to carefully choose the presents so that all of them fit into a rectangular chimney.

All presents must be center-aligned due to *magical physics* issues (i.e. placing two small presents side-by-side is not allowed). The presents can be rotated, but four of the faces must be parallel to that of the chimney. A present fits in the chimney if both its width and length are `<=` those of chimney after rotation.

### Task

Given the dimensions of the presents and the chimney, determine the maximum number of presents that fit in the chimney (i.e. sum of the presents' heights is `<=` that of the chimney). All dimensions are positive integers.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

Presents and chimney are given as `[width, length, height]`.

```
Presents: [[6, 6, 4], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]
Chimney: [6, 6, 6]
Answer: 3
Explanation: Use three small cubes.
(Placing two or more cubes above or below the single large box is not allowed)

Presents: [[6, 10, 9], [10, 7, 6], [10, 7, 5], [10, 7, 4], [5, 10, 10]]
Chimney: [6, 5, 999]
Answer: 0
Explanation: No present fits in the chimney

Presents: [[1, 2, 6], [1, 6, 2], [2, 1, 6], [2, 6, 1], [6, 1, 2], [6, 2, 1]]
Chimney: [2, 6, 6]
Answer: 6
Explanation: All six presents can be rotated to [2, 6, 1],
which fits the chimney and takes up only 1 unit of height

Presents: [[1, 2, 6], [1, 6, 2], [2, 1, 6], [2, 6, 1], [6, 1, 2], [6, 2, 1]]
Chimney: [1, 6, 6]
Answer: 3
Explanation: All six presents can be rotated to [1, 6, 2]

Presents: [[1, 2, 6], [1, 6, 2], [2, 1, 6], [2, 6, 1], [6, 1, 2], [6, 2, 1]]
Chimney: [1, 3, 13]
Answer: 2
Explanation: All six presents can be rotated to [1, 2, 6]
```

Comment: `All presents must be center-aligned due to magical physics issues` mean all thing differ pos on one direction, or the direction is given?

Comment: In all your test cases the height of the chimney is `>=`  every dimension in the list of presents. May we assume that to be true in all cases?

Comment: Can we throw an error instead of outputting `0` if no presents fit?

Comment: Suggested test case: `[[6, 10, 9], [10, 7, 6], [10, 7, 5], [10, 7, 4], [5, 10, 10], [1, 6, 7]], [6, 7, 21] -> 3`

Comment: Sorry for late response. @ l4m2: The intention is that all the presents are stacked vertically and no other direction. @ Shaggy: No, the chimney height can be smaller than any present's dimensions, and 0 is the correct answer in that case. Throwing instead of outputting 0 is not allowed.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 130 bytes

```python
lambda W,L,H,a:sum(0<=(H:=H-i)for i in sorted(min(h+H*(w>W or l>L)for h,w,l in permutations(b))for b in a));from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tY67jsIwEEX7/YopbfBKcUKAsBvqFPQULIUjEsVS/JBjhPbrgx9BGwo6VhrJ13funBn9azsls602Y1v@jD0T9YXBkRxIRdhuuAqUfJeo2pXVJ8etMsCBSxiUsc0FCS5Rt6wW6LY/guv1@0PIdORGep/TjRFXyyxXckA1Ds3aNxjGX61RArhtjFWqH4AL7aiLURsuLWrRmkCs0ym@q7PTKQFfL@QZ44/ZfE6gKIqJQBP382EvNo440/lMhzV5zNPkCZn@nUTDxsgI1uMOOrkxS71cBzedpM88Uel/UTPnZe/Bjnc)

Answer (score 3):

## Python3, 217 bytes:

```py
lambda c,p:max(max(f(c,[*i]))for i in P(p,len(p)))
from itertools import*
P=permutations
def f(c,p,H=0,k=0):
 yield k
 if p:
  for w,l,h in P(p[0],3):
   if c[0]>=w>0<l<=c[1]and H+h<=c[2]:yield from f(c,p[1:],H+h,k+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tY87b8MgFIV3/4o7muQOxq7T2IozRhmzUwbXDxn5ASJUaX69C9iRkqFbK0A693L4zkXdTSenZK/0fCo@5qEcP@sSKlT5WH6H7rRhhWwjOCGt1CBATHAJFQ7NFCpCSNBqOYIwjTZSDlcQo5LabIJLoRo9fpnSCDldg7ppwZEUnosI@yIieQB30Qw19AGIFpStwSXccMBuTWERx8Q5wVkqWx6L2zE6DIeiYpSXUw3nbeeKmOcLzY/jkxjNOdpr7LeUzEqLyYSnkO3QLo7MCrD7jSOwGMHtX6T9evD0PMUsy1YAjRAy53Xi3QKfdPqkfUq6@Gn0SowfA1GftyD8bI8p6NqNfZc6ufPdeJXO8wpdAP@BTWwz@Rvu/AM)

Comment: [225 bytes](https://tio.run/##tZAxb8MgEIV3fsWNJrnB2E1bW2WNMmanDG5sKyg2IEKU5te7gB0pGbq1AqTH4@57J@zNH40u362btvxzGprxq23ggLYem@8snj47oFgpSWlvHChQGvaZxaHTmaWUkt6ZEZTvnDdmOIMarXF@Rfbcdm68@MYro8@k7XqIJIs7nuOJ57QmcFPd0MKJgOqF5NzWrvMXpwnEpCsOeFzSRC6xjB2hEq4f/BCMRrcwRMmS3K2P8VLIeqamsVKiYLXE8IynNaOTdUr7bJuJVwxLoggCwn6RCKJAiPsXGb6APLRvsKqqBcByhCrWRvEWgA9686BTymauZ/kzsbgPxFLejEiz3adgi1skl0X5mtxikbHmGToD/gNbBrP8G@70Aw)

Comment: @jezza_99 Thanks, updated

Comment: Haha and can save another byte using `c[0]>=w>0<l<=c[1]` instead of `w<=c[0]and l<=c[1]`

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 72 bytes

```
Ｆθ«≔Ｅ³Ｅ³§ι⁺κμι≔Φ⁺ιＥι⮌κ⬤κ¬›μ§ηνι¿ι⊞υ⌊Ｅι⊟κ»≔⟦⟧ζＷ⁻υζＦ№υ⌊ι⊞ζ⌊ιＩＬΦζ¬›Σ…ζ⊕κ↨η⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBNS8QwED3bXzHHCUQQlb30tBaUBZWix9JD6M5uwqbpmiarVvztdfqh7h52GMgwee/lvVRa@apRtu83jQd8E/CVXCzb1mwdPqk93kiYj2VYuTV9oJGQ29jiTkItuCQYkf5x7o0N5HFEmInLxwsdyLeEuxG/tHZgPzcBHzypAV//62sJThwJmw2gEZDHVmNkReNMHWuclfNmP6oy8juZPRSlhI4X79pYAmQGm4nDTsCYMmuiC8dihgWmF7qTZZrk3jA0U23AR3LboH8TdqcBXpmQfVaWMs2O@HLlKk81uUDrOfad4h/gdFdiqrTvi6JYSOC@ZcvFtYShz4zDPIEXZdlfHuwP) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆθ«
```

Loop over the presents.

```
≔Ｅ³Ｅ³§ι⁺κμι
```

Rotate them 120° and 240° around a corner.

```
≔Φ⁺ιＥι⮌κ⬤κ¬›μ§ηνι
```

Also rotate them 180° around their length axis, then filter on which orientations fit in the chimney.

```
¿ι⊞υ⌊Ｅι⊟κ
```

If there were any then push the shortest such orientation to the predefined empty list.

```
»≔⟦⟧ζＷ⁻υζＦ№υ⌊ι⊞ζ⌊ι
```

Sort the list of heights.

```
ＩＬΦζ¬›Σ…ζ⊕κ↨η⁰
```

Find the maximum number of presents that will fit.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org)<sup>*</sup>, 128 bytes

** This code relies on a specific implementation of `sort()`. The engine used on TIO is Node 11.6.0. This was also succesfully tested with Node 16.14.0.*

*-4 thanks to [@tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh)*

Expects `(w,l,h,a)` where `w,l,h` are the dimensions of the chimney and `a` is the list of dimensions for the presents.

```javascript
(w,l,h,a)=>a.map(a=>(g=H=>m=n?([W,L,H]=a.sort(_=>-40%n--),W>w|L>l|H>g()?m:H):1/0)(n=42)).sort((a,b)=>a-b).map(v=>n+=(h-=v)>=0)|n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tY6xboMwEIb3PgVLpTvVpjaBVEQ6Z2XIngGhykkTkghMFCKy8O4U21SN1HRrpZP8@fz7uzvpTrfby/F85ab52A17GuDGKnZgGknpsNZn0KSgpIxUTWYJ@ZqtWFaQDtvmcoV3UjwWz4ZzZGt161eq6jNVAi7rRYYL@SoQDMURos@DZhtr5ht08o6UeSE4cOpQkcDeDNvGtE21C6umhD3MWeArz/0ZFyNHLLD1CxaITz8sCQvSNJ08Uow3@8XC2@i94@SO3bDE56V4II6@15Nuuje51tdOcur6rLQ4d91oQpt54Jb/656NL7O/kQ@f)

#### How?

The way we generate the 6 possible rotations of a present is very hackish but pretty short. It basically goes like that:

```javascript
for(let n = 42; n;) {
  a.sort(_ => -40 % n--);
}
```

The callback function of `sort()` ignores its arguments, making the sort independent of the content of the array. The result is solely based on the current value of \$n\$, which is decremented after each iteration. More specifically, we get either \$0\$ if \$n\in\{1,2,4,5,8,10,20,40\}\$ or a negative integer otherwise.

The constants \$-40\$ and \$42\$ were chosen such that all distinct rotations are eventually generated *and* we end up with exactly \$n=0\$ when the last one has been processed.

You can [follow this link](https://tio.run/##Hcw9C8JADAbgvb/iHSq5QnuIOHlUUXF1cXAQ0cOenyUnvapI6W@vsYEE8uYhd/u24VTdnnXGvnBdV7oaFjl2NKeUFtJL2qcRpILE7D7YuNpE0dlX6o9Z0vHIgE2CRpzVwVe1OiCfIhsPMQBnWWLk8tcP9xVv9d3fWBH1@clz8KXTpb@oY9wIaRE3QV9tULIkmIFQvJ4yJ6DderXdUwvO44bbY/8haFsUvTVR23U/) to see the different steps of the process.

Comment: Maybe you should specify the version of interpreter instead of claim it as "JavaScript". As behavior of `a.sort(_=>3%k++-2)` is certainly defined by interpreter.

Comment: 134: `(w,l,h,a)=>a.map(a=>(g=H=>m=n?([W,L,H]=a,a=--n%2?[W,H,L]:[H,L,W],W>w|L>l|H>g()?m:H):1/0)(n=6)).sort((a,b)=>a-b).map(v=>n+=(h-=v)>=0)|n`

Comment: @tsh Thank you for the suggestions. I've added two examples of engines for which this works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 21 bytes

```
εœʒ@¨P}€θß}²Oª{ηÅΔO‹θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3Najk09Ncji0IqD2UdOaczsOz689tMn/0Krqc9sPt56b4v@oYee5Hf//R0eb6SgYGugoWMbqKESDGOY6CmZIbFMktgmIbQpRb2gAlgAqBkrFxnKBzAEqMTKMBQA)

*+2 bytes: fixed a bug found by Jonathan Allan*

Assumes that all chimney dimensions are positive.

```
εœʒ@¨P}€θß}
ε         } # map over boxes
 œ          #   permutations (all possible rotations)
  ʒ   }     #   filter:
   @¨P      #     first two dimensions are less than or equal to the
                  first two dimensions of the chimney
       €θ   #   for each get last element (the height)
         ß  #   minimum
```

This gets a list of the smallest height you can get by rotating the box in a way that fits the chimney or "" if it doesn't fit at all.

```
²Oª{ηÅΔO‹θ
²Oª        # append sum of the second input to the list
   {       # sort
    η      # prefixes
     ÅΔ    # get the index of the first element such that:
       O‹θ #   the sum is greater than the last element of second input
```

The sum of the second input is there to guarantee that there is a prefix with larger sum than the height of the chimney.

Comment: `[[6, 10, 9], [10, 7, 6], [10, 7, 5], [10, 7, 4], [5, 10, 10], [1, 6, 7]]` and `[6, 7, 21]`  returns `6`, but it should be `3`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 28 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Ëá fÈÅí§NÅ eÃmÎÍÎÃÍËT±Z§(XµD
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=y%2bEgZsjF7adOxSBlw23Ozc7DzctUsVqnKFi1RA&input=W1sxLCAyLCA2XSwgWzEsIDYsIDJdLCBbMiwgMSwgNl0sIFsyLCA2LCAxXSwgWzYsIDEsIDJdLCBbNiwgMiwgMV1dCjEsIDMsIDEz)

```
Ëá fÈÅí§NÅ eÃmÎÍÎÃÍËT±Z§(XµD     :Implicit input of array U=presents and integers V=width, W=depth & X=height
Ë                                :Map U
 á                               :  Permutations
   f                             :  Filter by
    È                            :  Passing each through a function
     Å                           :    Slice off first element
      í                          :    Interleave with
        N                        :      Array of all inputs
         Å                       :      Slice off first element (X is ignored)
       §                         :      Reducing each pair by <=
           e                     :    All true?
            Ã                    :  End filter
             m                   :  Map
              Î                  :    First element (present height)
               Í                 :  Sort
                Î                :  First element
                 Ã               :End map
                  Í              :Sort
                   Ë             :Map each D
                    T±           :  Increment T (initially 0) by
                      Z          :    0
                       §(        :    <=
                         XµD     :    X, decremented by D
                                 :Implicit output of last element
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 29 bytes

```
K_EsmghK=+Zhhd_#SmSf.AtgVKT.p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3zvetTg3PcPbVjsqIyMlXjk4NzhNz7EkPcw7RK/g///oaEMdBSMdBbNYHQUQ0wzIAzGBQoZQUSOwqCGIaQYWNYIyQWpiY7mg2sxiAQ)

#### Explanation

Uses a simple greedy algorithm, always choosing the shortest present until no more fit.

```
K_EsmghK=+Zhhd_#SmSf.AtgVKT.pdQ    # implicitly add dQ to the end
                                   # implicitly assign Q = eval(input())
K_E                                # assign K to the second input reversed
                 m            Q    # map Q over lambda d
                   f       .pd     # filter permutations of d over lambda T
                       gVKT        # vectorize >= over K and T
                    .At            # true if the last two element are true (we've now filtered out orientations which don't fit in the chimney)
                  S                # sort (this orders the orientations from shortest to tallest)
                S                  # sort (this orders our presents shortest to tallest)
              _#                   # filter out empty lists (avoids indexing errors)
   s                               # sum of
    m                              # map over lambda d
     ghK                           # first element of K is greater than or equal to
        =+Zhhd                     # Z, assigned to Z + first element of the first element of d
```