# CGAC2022 Day 22: Present stack headache, Part 2

Tags: code-golf, 3d, packing

Part of [**Code Golf Advent Calendar 2022**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25251/announcing-code-golf-advent-calendar-2022-event-challenge-sandbox) event. See the linked meta post for details.

---

Santa has a bunch of presents wrapped in cuboid boxes of various sizes. As his sled flies above a chimney, a stack of presents will be automatically dropped through it. Santa wants to carefully choose the presents so that all of them fit into a rectangular chimney.

All presents must be center-aligned due to *magical physics* issues (i.e. placing two small presents side-by-side is not allowed). The presents can be rotated, but four of the faces must be parallel to that of the chimney. A present fits in the chimney if both its width and length are `<=` those of chimney after rotation.

[On second thought](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/255793/78410), Santa decides that choosing the maximum number of presents is not great, because a single large present is more valuable than a bunch of tiny ones.

### Task

Given the dimensions of the presents and the chimney, determine the maximum **volume** of presents that fit in the chimney (i.e. sum of the presents' heights is `<=` that of the chimney). All dimensions are positive integers.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

Presents and chimney are given as `[width, length, height]`.

```
Presents: [[6, 6, 4], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]
Chimney: [6, 6, 6]
Answer: 152
Explanation: Use the large box and a small cube.

Presents: [[6, 10, 9], [10, 7, 6], [10, 7, 5], [10, 7, 4], [5, 10, 10]]
Chimney: [6, 5, 999]
Answer: 0
Explanation: No present fits in the chimney

Presents: [[1, 2, 6], [1, 6, 2], [2, 1, 6], [2, 6, 1], [6, 1, 2], [6, 2, 1]]
Chimney: [2, 6, 6]
Answer: 72 (=6*(1*2*6))
Explanation: All six presents can be rotated to [2, 6, 1],
which fits the chimney and takes up only 1 unit of height

Presents: [[1, 2, 6], [1, 6, 2], [2, 1, 6], [2, 6, 1], [6, 1, 2], [6, 2, 1]]
Chimney: [1, 6, 6]
Answer: 36
Explanation: All six presents can be rotated to [1, 6, 2]

Presents: [[1, 2, 6], [1, 6, 2], [2, 1, 6], [2, 6, 1], [6, 1, 2], [6, 2, 1]]
Chimney: [1, 3, 13]
Answer: 24
Explanation: All six presents can be rotated to [1, 2, 6]
```

Comment: This question more likely a combination of two problems: 1. rotate the present so it has smallest height while fit the chimney; 2. A classical knapsack problem.

Comment: @tsh Yeah, right. This is what you get when you're pressed for challenges...

Comment: @Arnauld fixed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 180 bytes

```python
lambda W,L,H,c:max(sum(h*w*l for h,w,l in a[::2])for a in P(c+[[0]*3]*len(c))if sum(min(h+H*(w>W or l>L)for h,w,l in P(b))for b in a[::2])<=H)
from itertools import*
P=permutations
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tY69boMwFEZ3nsJSF9vxgKGkBZXMDBnYMlAGQ0BY8g8yjmifnmKgKgzdWulKPv70@Vz3n7bTKnztzdSm75NgsrozcCNXkpE6kewDDg8JOzxiAVptQEdGIgBXgBVJEpTIZczdc1ifisIvcVhi0ShYI8Rb4B5LrmB3yjAcLzcw18Xlig6qHFZoSaqd@C3NkNcaLQG3jbFaiwFw2WtjsZenfWPkwzLLtRqm3nBlYQvPBKxTFOv5XM4cEODmFywR8p52goiAOI43BfXnm2s7eJmVO452vOyJ1j71j87g51N02blKluj7J3RL1y51eF7SYEPXOWrpv2nDOQz/xjt9AQ)

It works on first two testcases. But It sadly timeout for third one.

\$O((2N+1)!)\$ solution, where \$N\$ is the number of presents.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org)<sup>*</sup>, 153 bytes

** This code relies on a specific implementation of `sort()`. The engine used on TIO is Node 11.6.0. This was also succesfully tested with Node 16.14.0.*

Expects `(w,l,h,a)` where `w,l,h` are the dimensions of the chimney and `a` is the list of dimensions for the presents.

```javascript
f=(w,l,h,a,V=o=0)=>a.map((b,i)=>f(w,l,h-(g=H=>m=n?([W,L,H]=b.sort(_=>-40%n--),W>w|L>l|H>g(v=W*L*H)?m:H):1/0)(n=42),a.filter(_=>i--),V+v),h<0|V<o?0:o=V)|o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tY6xboMwEED3fgVLJTs9qE0gFSg2KwMzDBGKnBQIFeAIEFn4d4oxVSM13VrpJL873727DzGI7tyW195s5Hs2TTlDN6jgAgJiJhnBjAurFleETlDOSa6/TVSwkPGaNQE6JBBBmLKT1cm2R0fGTYc8N6aJIeG3MeLVGPICDSzZRJsQB7UfYp@@Eowa5tgYhJWXVZ@1arJUU/HLgOGyJ2O8lwHxJYvxKKezbDpZZVYlC5SjHRg6Dgf9OunMNhgqfsEU46cfFhcMz/NWDyVzpkYUvM3eO3bveFnm6n5KHojt7/Posl2bltLXTXSt6l6qcLdU7RVVzwM3/V/3dv7Z/o18@gQ)

Just like [my answer to the previous challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255801/58563), this is sponsored by the Ministry of Silly Sorts.

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, 221 bytes:

```py
lambda c,p:max(max(f(c,[*i]))for i in P(p,len(p)))
from itertools import*
P=permutations
def f(c,p,H=0,v=0):
 yield v
 if p:
  for w,l,h in P(p[0],3):
   if c[0]>=w>0<l<=c[1]and H+h<=c[2]:yield from f(c,p[1:],H+h,w*l*h+v)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tY8/b8MgEMV3f4objXODsZu2tuKMUcbslMH1HxkJG0Ro0nx6F7AjJUO3VoD07nj83qFvdlBT/q7NfKg@ZlmPn20NDepyrL9jf/q4QZYITkivDAgQE5xijbKbYk0IiXqjRhC2M1YpeQYxamVsEp0q3Znxy9ZWqOkctV0PnqTxWKV4qVJSRnATnWzhEoHoQbsafMIVJQ5rCks55t4J3tK4cl9d9@lO7qqGUV5PLRw3gy8yXi60ME5IYrTk6K7xmshk2FzIrI2YbHyI2Su6xZE5AW6/cASWIfj9i3Tfjx6eb7EoihVAU4TCe714c8AHvX3QIWW7@Gn6TMzuA9GQtyDCbPcp6NrNQpd6@Rq62Sq95xm6AP4Dm7tm/jfc@Qc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 80 bytes

```
Ｆθ«≔Ｅ³Ｅ³§ι⁺κμζ≔Φ⁺ζＥζ⮌κ⬤κ¬›μ§ηνζ¿ζ⊞υ⟦Πι⌊Ｅζ⊟κ⟧»Ｉ⌈ＥΦＥＸ²ＬυΦυ﹪÷ιＸ²μ²¬›↨Ｅι⌊λ¹↨η⁰↨Ｅι⌈λ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/BS8MwFMbP7q/I8RUi6JRddqqKMrASvJYeQputYWkyk7SOin97fUnjNg@GhDx4v@9976tbbmvD1TRtjSXwkZGvxVXunNxpKPgB7ihJX@43uhFHkJQw1TvYU9JleCgZs/VJ8yyVFxYiMc5a/N7FIKwTsI98rlRQvxkPL1bwwHfn@S0lOrsYLLcExoyw3rXQU1Iya5q@9iARKKSWXd9BsmHmEC0q1H0vmJXawyN3HvvHE5c2DCUzn1gtKXkVeudxfDBNfbQq0EgZ2Gj/JAfZiBj9V9IFdhnXvAzywDFmmC3P26kA3eKLTcx3M8f7w6YNExvOeprKslxRgve@wuToGu4/ZahneFVV0/WgfgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Based on my answer to [CGAC2022 Day 21: Present stack headache](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/255793).

```
Ｆθ«
```

Loop over the presents.

```
≔Ｅ³Ｅ³§ι⁺κμι
```

Rotate them 120° and 240° around a corner.

```
≔Φ⁺ιＥι⮌κ⬤κ¬›μ§ηνι
```

Also rotate them 180° around their length axis, then filter on which orientations fit in the chimney.

```
¿ζ⊞υ⟦Πι⌊Ｅζ⊟κ⟧
```

If there were any then push the shortest such orientation to the predefined empty list along with the volume of the present.

```
»Ｉ⌈ＥΦＥＸ²ＬυΦυ﹪÷ιＸ²μ²¬›↨Ｅι⌊λ¹↨η⁰↨Ｅι⌈λ¹
```

Generate the powerset of the list of presents that fit, filter on those whose height fits in the chimney, and output the maximum volume.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 38 bytes

```
K_EeSmsm*FkdfghKshMTyhM_#SmSf.AtgVKT.p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3zveNTU4tzhXyy07JS09w7s4wzekMsM3Xjk4NzhNz7EkPcw7RK/g///oaDMdBSAyidVRiDbSUQAhHMxYLqhas1gA)

#### Explanation

Picks the shortest orientation for each present, then looks at all possible sets of presents and picks the highest volume one which fits.

```
K_EeSmsm*FkdfghKshMTyhM_#SmSf.AtgVKT.pdQ    # implicitly add dQ to the end
                                            # implicitly assign Q = eval(input())
K_E                                         # assign K to the second input reversed
                          m            Q    # map Q over lambda d
                            f       .pd     # filter permutations of d over lambda T
                                gVKT        # vectorize >= over K and T
                             .At            # true if the last two element are true (we've now filtered out orientations which don't fit in the chimney)
                           S                # sort (this orders the orientations from shortest to tallest)
                         S                  # sort (this orders our presents shortest to tallest)
                       _#                   # filter out empty lists (avoids indexing errors)
                     hM                     # map each element to the first element of itself
            f       y                       # filter the power set over lambda T
             ghKshMT                        # first element of K >= sum of the first element(s) of T (leaving only sets of presents that fit)
     m                                      # map over lambda d
      s                                     # sum of
       m   d                                # map d over lambda k
        *Fk                                 # k reduced on multiplication (we've now mapped the sets to their volumes)
   eS                                       # take the largest element
```